# Use ValidatesOnDataErrors on a property of a user control

Tags: wpf, validation, binding, dependency-properties

I have a view model that implements IDataErrorInfo that has the validation implementation.
I also have a user control, that contains a label and a textBox.
When I use ValidatesOnDataErrors=True on the Text property of my control, if the Text is not valid the whole control becomes red (even the label).
How can I handle the validation error inside my user control so that only the textBox to become red?

```
<controls:TextBoxControl Label="Test:"
                         Text="{Binding PersonalModel.Test, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
```

And my control implementation has a dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxControl),
              new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
```

Comment: You will need a binding in the textbox. And that should have at least NotifyOnValidationError="True" on it's binding. But i think your design is a bad idea.

Comment: I have a binding in my user control for the textBox. I will try to add NotifyOnValidationError to see what happens. Why do you say it's a bad idea?

Comment: If you're labelling controls then imo you'd do better going with a contentcontrol. Then you can put a textbox, checkbox, button, whatever you like in it. And you wouldn't have created a boundary around your textbox.

Comment: It sounds smarter than my implementation. Do you have an example or a link with something similar?

Comment: See editrow in here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29777.wpf-property-list-editing.aspx